# Eclipse keeps crashing after launching AVD

Tags: 14.04, permissions, java, android, eclipse

When I start eclipse, everything is fine, but when I start AVD, eclipse crashes.
**Further Details:**
my first step was typing `sudo -i` in terminal.(if I don't type this, I can't cd to the location of eclipse)
Next, I've used `cd` to the location of eclipse, like this:

```
cd /home/myusername/Desktop/programming/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/eclipse
```

when I type & enter `ls`, every file in `eclipse` folder is shown including the eclipse application.
then, I've entered `sudo ./eclipse`, eclipse starts. everything is fine, nothing unusual.
I then, opened Android virtual device manager & created a new AVD. but when I started it, eclipse crashes, & I can never start it again until I restart Ubuntu.(before eclipse crashes, there's something in the console about some file that is `read-only` , although I used `sudo ./eclipse` to start eclipse as super user).
I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Anyone???this issue is **REALLY** Getting on my nerve!!

Comment: try 'sudo chmod -R +rw [eclipse_folder]'

Answer (score 0):

there was a huge bug from eclipse causing it to crash from 13.10

It is still unresolved so it may affect you. Known issue in kubuntu

Try to change the GTK2 theme from oxygen to Raleigh if u have oxygen. alternatively try the following to disable just for éclipse:
$ GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /opt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/eclipse/eclipse

bug entry:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1241101